# Unable to undo removal in Zsh

Tags: zsh, undo, rm

I run at path/test

```
rm -r *
```

The [tutorial](http://www.ee.ryerson.ca/guides/zsh-intro.pdf) says that I can undo the change by

> If one of these fancyeditor commands
>   changes your command line in a way you
>   did not intend, you can  undo changes
>   withˆ_,ifyou can get it out of your
>   keyboard, orˆXˆU,otherwise.

However, I did not get the files back by pressing Ctrl-x Ctrl-u or Ctrl-x-u. 
I also tried ^_ unsuccessfully by pressing Shift-6 Shift-- or Shift-6--.

**How can you undo the removal in Zsh?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The *undo* ability is a feature of the Z Line Editor, the editor that you use while typing at the command line. It lets you undo things you type on the command line, like any good text editor. But it won't let you undo commands that you execute.

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding.  They're talking about undoing changes to the command-line, before you press enter, not undoing the results of a command.